# How can nftables be configured using a declarative specification?

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, linux-networking, nftables

How can nftables be configured using a declarative specification? I've been reading up on Firewalld, iptables commands, etc. I'm looking for a way to write the rules in JSON, YAML, TOML, etc. and just "apply" them.

Answer (score 1):

I think regular nft syntax is just as declarative as anything else. Just include:

```
flush ruleset
```

At the beginning of your rules file, and then:

```
nft -f ruleset.nft
```

Will configure exactly the rules defined in your `ruleset.nft` file.

Writing rules in JSON or some other syntax doesn't make them any more declaritive (nft does support JSON input and output with the `-j` option, but you'll need to explicitly flush the ruleset with `nft flush ruleset` before loading the JSON rules, and you won't have an atomic operation in this case).